# Is this the right way to create and call a class for an iphone application?

Tags: iphone, class, methods

I have this class
loader.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class Reachability;
@interface loader : NSObject {

}
- (void)startLoading;
@end

loader.m

#import "loader.h"
#import "Reachability.h"
@implementation loader
- (void)startLoading{
    NSLog(@"Check network");
}
@end
```

Is the code bellow the correct way to include the above class and use it

in my .h file I put

```
@class loader;
```

and in the .m file

```
#import "loader.h"
```

and I use this code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
loader *myLoader = [loader alloc];
[myLoader startLoading];
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

is this the correct way? to use a class??

I want loader class to be in change and check for internet connectivity and I try to start from somewhere :)
thanks in advance :)

Comment: An advice for you is don't use pre, br to format your question, in SO, we don't need them. You can use double enter to go to the next line and use the button 111  (in your textbox header) or ``to format code

Comment: Then you will see your code is nicer, having color and highlighted

Comment: In Objective-C it is conventional for Class names to have a capital letter. `Loader` instead of `loader` would be better. Also, maybe it might be better to give `Loader` a more meaningful name? What does it load? If it loads a webpage, call it `WebpageLoader` or if it loads scores from a leaderboard, call it `ScoreLoader` etc.

Comment: thanks for the tips really appreciate them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fine for you to do so, except some parts:

- You are leaking the myLoader by not releasing or auto release it
- You may need an init method so that you can populate some data (it is a convention for me not an error)

Comment: You may not need an init, but you still need to call it so NSObject's init gets to run...

Comment: Yeah, you may need to call NSObject init but in terms of theory, you don't really need

Comment: So in order to fix this and be 100% correct is to alloc and init and after calling my method to release it [[loader alloc] init] and then after that [loader release]. Am i right?

Comment: Let me ask you more few questions: what do you intend your loader to do. Does that job in the main thread or in another thread. If it is in main thread, you can possible release after you call. But, I suspect that in your particular case, because you are calling Reachability, which potentially runs on another thread, you should do it differently

Comment: You should declare a instance varible, a property, alloc init in the viewDidLoad and then call release in the dealloc method

Comment: I have a loading screen and I want during this view to create a class that will handle all init stuff (check internet connectivity, check online server version data, check data version with local data, update local data if needed that's all). So I believe that it will be my main thread. I will wait this to finish and then move on with the loading views. I should probably create a protocol to handle better the return data but right now I use NSNotificationCenter cause I find it a little bit easier :). Thanks for your tips again :)

Comment: Another advice: don't do all of your stuff on the main thread. Because if you do all of that, the screen freeze, users cannot touch or do anything on your screen. No gesture is recognized